# Updating a column with a constant gives the error ‘Subquery returned more than 1 value’

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting the error

> 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

When trying to update all the records from a constant value.

Any ideas what causes this issue.

Code:

```
UPDATE MembershipUser
SET EMail = 'chamika@mailinator.com'
```

Comment: Is that really all your query? Because the error mentions subquery, also maybe post your table structure/give more information about the query you want to execute.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: Yes. This is my query, as I need to replace all the emails to a dummy email (so that all the test emails i send will not go to actual users).

Comment: @gotqn Thanks for the input.... There is a trigger on update and that causes the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @gotqn, the cause of this error was that the table was having a trigger which fires on update. Simply disabling the trigger and running the update statement resolved the issue.